# mongodb doesnt save 2 objects inside the main object

Tags: mongodb, draftjs

I want to save an object that has and object and array inside it. But when I end up saving the data in the mongo, it doesnt save a few properties.

like "entityMap": {}, data: {}

body =

```
{ entityMap: {},
  blocks:
   [ { key: '637gr',
       text: 'Books selected for the you  ',
       type: 'header-four',
       depth: 0,
       inlineStyleRanges: [Array],
       entityRanges: [],
       data: {} } ] }
```

Heres how my mongo schema structured.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
    body: {
      type: {},
      required: false
    },
    templateName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    subject: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    googleId: {
      type: String,
      required:true
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  });

mongoose.model('books', bookSchema);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the property with type `{}`, mongoose uses the `Schema.Types.Mixed` type. This way the property may contain anything, but mongoose won't detect changes made to it. You have to manually tell mongoose that the property was modified:

```
book.body = { foo: { bar: { quux: 'foo' } } }
book.markModified('body');
book.save()
```

[Mongoose SchemaTypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: It didnt work, After making this change, I see no changes in the new objects added in the mongodb.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the markModified bit, I updated my post

Comment: nope didnt work, Heres my changes                                                                     
  const book = new Book({
  body,
  subject,
  templateName,
  googleId, 
  dateSent: Date.now()
});


try {
  book.markModified('body');
  await book.save();
  res.send(book);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(' err while saving =', err );
  res.status(422).send(err);
}

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using? Can you paste your entire schema? By the way I was wrong about having to declare the property as Schema.Types.Mixed, you can simply use `{}` to declare the type.

Comment: {}  thats what i had earlier,  I've pasted the full mongo schema above in the question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the confusion. Try setting `body` after initializing the object - that matches better with how they use it in the documentation.